# Как правильно разместить пакет на packagist?

Tags: php, composer, packagist

Собственно не нашел на русском документации. Может у кого есть и поделитесь. Вот я создал `composer.json` а дальше как ? И вообще что делать почитал бы с удовольствием.

Comment: Информация на сайте packagist.org: https://packagist.org/about Если тяжело с английским, можно открыть эту ссылку в гугл хром, и включить перевод на русский.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Документации на русском нет только на английском.

Если кратко то вот порядок действий.

1. Зарегистрироваться на packagist
2. В проекте создать composer.json указав vendor/package (выбрать незанятый vendor).
3. На packagist нажать на кнопку submit или пройти по ссылке https://packagist.org/packages/submit
4. Указать адрес проекта на github или bitbucket
5. Он проверит composer.json если имя вендора свободно он предложит создать проект, также поищет похожие проекты

Есть еще и дополнительные шаги как сделать автообновления проекта и тд, но лучше почитать в доке на английском.

Comment: а где конкретно в английской документации это написано ?

Comment: вот здесь https://packagist.org/

Publish It

Login or register on this site, then hit the submit button in the menu.

Once you entered your public repository URL in there, your package will be automatically crawled periodically. You just have to make sure you keep the composer.json file up to date.